# How to change time_format from time_iso8601 in fluentd and send to clickhouse?

Tags: datetime, nginx, fluentd, clickhouse

There is nginx.conf

```sh
....
http {
....
    log_format  main  '"$remote_addr" "$time_iso8601"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
.....
}
```

Logs access.log

```sh
"127.0.0.1" "2019-12-28T10:53:20+00:00"
"127.0.0.1" "2019-12-28T10:53:20+00:00"
```

There is fluent (td-agent)

```xml
td-agent.conf
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/nginx/access.log
  pos_file /tmp/nginx-access-log.pos
  tag nginx
  format /"(?<remote_addr>[0-9,\.]*)" "(?<time_iso8601>[^ ]*)"/
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
</source>


<filter foo.bar>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    time_iso8601 ${Time.strptime(record['time_iso8601'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').iso8601}
  </record>
</filter>

<match nginx>
    @type clickhousejson
    host 127.0.0.1
    port 8123
    database fluent
    table fluent
    datetime_name time_iso8601
</match>
```

In clickhouse I created a database and a table.

```sql
create database fluent;

CREATE TABLE fluent.fluent (
  Date Date MATERIALIZED toDate(DateTime), 
  remoteip String, 
  DateTime DateTime) 
ENGINE = MergeTree(Date, DateTime, 8192);
```

Logs are sent to clickhouse.

```sh
│          │ 0000-00-00 00:00:00 │
```

How to change time_format from time_iso8601 to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S in fluentd (td-agent) and send to clickhouse?

Answer (score 1):

When there are unknown or not directly supported date formats you need to insert to a ClickHouse table, instead of changing the date in the origin, you can try to parse it in ClickHouse no matter the format it has.

You can try it using the [parseDateTimeBestEffort](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#parsedatetimebesteffort) function.

For your case, you can create the table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fluent.fluent (
  DateTime String,
  remoteip String,
  Date Date MATERIALIZED toDate(parseDateTimeBestEffort(DateTime)),  
  ParsedDateTime DateTime MATERIALIZED parseDateTimeBestEffort(DateTime) 
ENGINE = MergeTree(Date, ParsedDateTime, 8192);
```

It stores the `DateTime` column as it comes in a `String` column and then materialize it using the `parseDateTimeBestEffort`.

If that doesn't do the trick, you can check the format in the `DateTime` column and try a manual parsing of the raw value using a combination of the toDateTime function and [substring](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-functions/#substring).